# Adding infobox to Google Maps Marker as HTML tag attribute (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show some information about a marker when clicking on it. I am dynamically adding the markers via AngularJS.

This is what I wrote:

```
<marker ng-repeat="i in list" position="[{{i.coordinates}}]" 
                           title="{{i.name}}" icon="./images/markerimg.png">
```

How do I augment this code to show a {{i.name}} also in the info box? Can I give a style to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

The above seems to be what you are looking for. You can find more detailed information at [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: click the link I provided and read through the example. It contains a working example :)

Comment: Thanks, but that requires me to change some working code and I cannot. I am not willing to change the ng-repeat.